# Why getting this error The name 'EncryptStringToBytes_Aes' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

When trying to encrypt string to bytes using Aes I'm getting this error message

> The name 'EncryptStringToBytes_Aes' does not exist in the current context

Here's my code

```
namespace Encryption learning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string encryption64xx = "BASE64";

            byte[] key = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x25, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x21, 0x21, 0x1F };
            byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xBC, 0xF0, 0xA3, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x12, 0x2A, 0xF0, 0xA3, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x13, 0xA2, 0xF0, 0xA3 };


            byte[] encrypted64x = EncryptStringTobytes_Aes(encryption64xx, key, iv);

            string encrypted64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted64x);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"teste.txt", encrypted64);





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better question than your last one. It is concise, has enough context and is only asking one question. Your issue is that `EncryptStringTobytes_Aes` doesn't exist or is not referenced properly (`using static ...something`).

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: why do you expect `EncryptStringTobytes_Aes` to exist?

Comment: Sorry for that. but again I did not get what could be missing I'm pretty sure it has been referenced my project has only one file which is the program.cs and the code is in it when I attempt to build does not run  when you say ( using static ) what do you mean by that could you clarify ?

Comment: I mean the only way that could compile is if that method were in a static class and you brought it in with a `using` statement. But forget that, I'm sure it is not the case. If you wrote `ShootMoonbeamRay()` would you expect it to compile? No, because that method doesn't exist, just like `EncryptStringTobytes_Aes` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`EncryptStringTobytes_Aes()` is a library method and it needs to be exported from an external library/package so that it can be used in your program.

According to [this Microsoft docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.configuration.encryption.encryptutilities.encryptstringtobytes_aes?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable), It is located in the Microsoft.Bot.Configuration.dll file which you can download using NuGet.

To do that from the solution explorer panel, right-click on your project name and select "manage NuGet packages". Find and select the  "Browse" tab from the panel on the left and to the search bar located under "Browse" type "Microsoft.Bot.Configuration" and hit enter. Download the first NuGet packet you see that matches the filename. After the NuGet packet is installed go to your program.cs file and add

`using Microsoft.Bot.Configuration.Encryption;`

to the top of your file.

Now you should be able to use this method